# Third party framework in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, gpuimage

my question is very general. Is it possible to use third-party framework in an iOS app project? I mean, does Apple allow developers to use frameworks like GPUImage (it is only an example) in their app? 
I found this two documents in which Apple says that it is possible in OSX but not in iOS. By your experience, is it correct what I found?
Thanks.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Framework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH56-SW1

Comment: you can always use third party libraries, even your own. I use my own frameworks or static libraries for my client projects

Comment: Do you have any official reference?

Comment: @KumarC You create your own framework with this https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework and a tutorial to create is this http://rayvinly.com/how-to-build-a-truly-universal-framework-for-ios-and-mac-with-just-a-single-codebase/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Apple will allow you to use third party libraries in your project, otherwise there wouldn't be this many third party libraries available.

The only restriction is that the library can not be loaded dynamically and should be compiled into the app binary.

Comment: Do you have any official reference?

Comment: Just see the [Linking to a Library or Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html) documenation. Here they talk about adding a library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I will quote popular example of third party SDK libraries like `Facebook sdk` and `youtube` for example. There are lot of example that can be proven for the use of third party library/SDK.